# Не получается сбилдить ServiceProvider из-за сгенерированног grpc клиента

Tags: c#, микросервисы, grpc

У меня есть grpc-клиент который автогенерируется через `Grpc.Core` и есть сервис в который инъектируется этот клиент. Выглядит так:

```
public ShoppingCartService(Products.ProductsClient client)
{
    _client = client;
}
```

В Program:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IShoppingCartService, ShoppingCartService>();
var app = builder.Build(); //Вот тут исключение

app.MapGrpcService<Products.ProductsClient>();
```

Получаю следующее исключение:

```
System.AggregateException: 
Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: CartService.Service.IShoppingCartService Lifetime: Transient
 ImplementationType: CartService.Service.ShoppingCartService':
 Unable to resolve service for type 'ProductService.Service.Products+ProductsClient' 
 while attempting to activate 'CartService.Service.ShoppingCartService'.)
```

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
'ProductService.Service.Products+ProductsClient' 
 while attempting to activate 'CartService.Service.ShoppingCartService'.
```

Я пытался добавить вот эту строчку (до и после `AddGrpc()`):

`builder.Services.AddTransient<Products.ProductsClient>();`,
но это не помогло, ошибка осталась той же. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а где сам интерфейс `IShoppingCartService`  //`ShoppingCartService:IShoppingCartService` вы в инъекции пишете `<IShoppingCartService, ShoppingCartService>`, а его не наследуете //`ImplementationType` ошибка наследования

Comment: 1. Что такое `ProductsClient`? 2. Почему `.AddGrpc();`, а не `AddGrpcClient<ProductsClient>()` как показано в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-7.0)?

Comment: `builder.Services.AddTransient<ShoppingCartService>();` `builder.Services.AddScope<ShoppingCartService>();` //если не используете Интерфейс, то просто сервис добавьте

Comment: @Dev18 Интереса ради, почему вы думаете, что там не реализован интерфейс? В ошибке ведь не пишет, что "не удалость создать ShoppingCartService, при попытке создания ...", там пишет наоборот, что при создании `ShoppingCartService` была неудачная попытка создания `ProductsClient`, ну а это сразу отметает все вопросы про `ShoppingCartService`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ //Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: CartService.Service.*IShoppingCartService* Lifetime: Transient, в первую очередь возник а где интерфейс если он в инъекции то почему не наследуется, сейчас вот читаю про фабрики, что вы скинули, такого не видела

Comment: @Dev18 Это скажем так, заголовок ошибки, который просто говорит "при создании данного сервиса возникла ошибка", сама ошибка (внутренняя) идет дальше, после `:`, в студии она дополнительно еще в раздел "внутренних ошибок" попадает, из которого автор вопроса также скопировал и вставил как 2-ю ошибку, ну и там мы видим прямым текстом написанную причину: `Unable to resolve service ProductsClient while attempting to activate ShoppingCartService` (Не удалось создать `ProductsClient`, при попытке создания `ShoppingCartService`). Так что, не смотрите поверхностно на ошибки)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, надо было добавить AddGrpcClient<>, запостите ответ, помечу галкой. Класс имплементировал интерфейс, дело было именно в отсутствии регистрации самого grpc-клиента

Comment: @daoistgu Можете написать его самостоятельно, я пасс...

Answer (score 0):

Перед `builder.Build()` надо было добавить строку `builder.AddGrpcClient<Products.ProductsClient>()`